# Debian 8 + PHP: /tmp/ Permission denied

Tags: debian, php-fpm, tmp

I had a website running fine on Debian 7 + PHP 5.6, and recently decided to upgrade my Debian installation to Debian 8. Everything went fine, except for a small thing.

While running the same code, seems like PHP is unable to write anything to `/tmp/`, now I get messages like:

```
errno: 2,
errstr: "ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied",
errcontext: {
    Filepath: "/tmp/phpVTUxDh",
    Options: null,
    Zip: {
       status: 0,
       statusSys: 0,
       numFiles: 12,
       filename: "/tmp/phpVTUxDh",
       comment: ""
    },
Status: true
```

Apparently the method `extractTo()` is having an hard time to write to `\tmp` is there any specific change on the system that could be causing this? What about the new systemd `PrivateTmp` thing?

I tried to add `PrivateTmp=false` to the files:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/lighttpd.service
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php5-fpm.service
```

However, it doesn't seem to do any difference there.

Anyway, any specific reason why `\tmp` is now always empty? Also,where is the new location of the tmp?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to check:

1) System user you run `php-fpm` as

2) AppArmor:

```
cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled
```

if enabled:

```
grep 'DENIED' /var/log/syslog or /var/log/auditd/auditd.log
```

3) Permissions on `/tmp`:

```
stat /tmp
```

4) `open_basedir` in PHP settings:

```
su -m <php_user> -c "php -i | grep -i open_basedir"
```

Also, when you modify systemd unit file, try reloading it first: `systemctl  daemon-reload` and then restart `php-fpm`.

Comment: 1) `www-data`; 2) NO; 3) `Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`; 4) `open_basedir => no value => no value`; However it's now working, your `systemctl daemon-reload` tip worked fine. ;) So... Even if I run it with `PrivateTmp=true` shouldn't PHP work? Why not? How can I take advantage of PrivateTmp without screwing PHP? Thx

Comment: In general, PrivateTmp should work just fine. It uses kernel namespaces and overrides /tmp location for a process. I just tested it on centos 7 server as I don't have debian on hand. `<?php
 $fp = fopen('/tmp/data.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, 'test');
fclose($fp);
?>
# cat ./systemd-private-ZnEQcW/tmp/data.txt
 test`

Comment: Keep in mind that privatetmp isolate tmp folder for a process and other processes cannot access it data, so 'sharing' via tmp will be impossible. It can also be a bug in systemd debian 8 uses, cannot say much without knowing your code or configuration specifics